# How to Increase Azure-hosted Integration Runtime JVM Heap Memory

Tags: azure-data-factory

We are using Azure Data Factories to upload SQL data (stored in ORC files) from Azure Data Lake into Azure Data Warehouse. We keep getting the following error on one specific table:

```
"errorCode": "2200",
"message": "ErrorCode=UserErrorJavaInvocationException,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error happened when invoking java, message: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:Java heap space.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.OrcTransferPlugin,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.JniExt.JavaBridgeException,Message=,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.HiveOrcBridge,'",
"failureType": "UserError",
"target": "ADLToADWCopy"
```

This table gave the same error when we uploaded from the source SQL DB into Azure Data Lake and we were able to resolve that by tweaking the JVM memory allocation on the self-hosted Integration Runtime machine:

```
setx _JAVA_OPTIONS "-Xms256m -Xmx16g" /M
```

Is there a way to pass something similar to the Azure-hosted Integration Runtime?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the chunks size of your data? how big is each chunk? I've seen this error with Parquet files as well, unfortunately you cannot modify the Azure IR (As far as I know), if you find a way it'd be nice to know, also you may want to create a ticket and provide the RunId with MS.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the chunk size. Is that thew write batch size? I did try reducing that from the default of 10,000 down to 100, but no luck on that. I may end up creating a ticket with MS, but my gut is telling me it's not a feature they have yet and we'll need to spin up a VM to do this copy...

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?